# Explain for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I was trying the below code. Kindly go through below code and help me understand what is the logic to get the below output.

I was trying to add only the first 10 values or first 9 values out of the given 11 values.

```
nums = [1,3,5,7,9,1,3,2,4,5,6]

def random(nums):
    count = 0
    for x in range(len(nums)-2):
        count = count + x
    return count
print("The random addition for above prog is")    
print(random(nums))
```

output:

```
The random addition for above prog is
36
```

when I replaced with `for x in range(len(nums)-2)` i am getting below o/p

```
The random addition for above prog is
45
```

when I replaced with `for x in range(len(nums))` i am getting below o/p

```
The random addition for above prog is
55
```

2. on what basis I should use the logic `range(len(nums)-2)` or `range(len(nums)-3)` in using the for loop.

Comment: Note that `x` isn't the members of `x`, its the indices of `x`. You would need `count = count + nums[x]` to get the number at index `x` (although there are better, more Pythonic ways of doing that, like slicing the list before iterating).

Comment: You don't use the values of your list. You only use the lists length. Your `for x in range(len(nums)-2):` could be written as `for x in range(9):`

Comment: Adding the first 9 values of `nums` could be done with `sum(nums[:9])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added index value that created by range, not list values.

```
count += x # this is one of [0,1...]
```

len and range's behavior is below.

- len returns number of value list contains

```
>>> nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> len(nums)
11
```

- range returns n length list start with 0(usable for list index)

```
>>> range(11)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

- python's for takes one value from list, and do something and take next one value...

```
for i in [1,3,2]:
  print(i)

1
3
2
```

If you want to take first 10 value of list and loop them, you can do below.

```
for i in range(10):
  print(nums[i])
```

length of list can create range's arg 10 with below

```
len(nums) - 1
# => 11 - 1
# => 10
```

integrate them for first 10 values of list

```
for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
  print(nums[i])
```

if you want sum random values

```
count = 0
>>> for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
...   print(i, nums[i])
...   count += nums[i]
... 
(0, 1)
(1, 3)
(2, 5)
(3, 7)
(4, 9)
(5, 1)
(6, 3)
(7, 2)
(8, 4)
(9, 5)
>>> count
40
>>>
```

If you want to just sum first 10 value of list with loop, you can write below

```
count = 0
for x in nums[:10]:
  count += x
```

`nums[:10]` returns list contains first 10 values of nums like `[1,3,5,...8]`

Comment: Thanks @ynishi..very helpful